# How to interpret the score test pvalue from a cox proportional hazard model with interaction term?

Tags: survival

Here is an example of my question:

```
set.seed(123)
x<-rnorm(100,2,3)
y<-rbinom(100,1,0.6)
years<-abs(rnorm(100,50,5))
event<-rbinom(100,1,0.7)
library(survival)
summary(coxph(Surv(years, event)~x*y))
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(years, event) ~ x * y)

  n= 100, number of events= 67 

       coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z Pr(>|z|)  
x    0.1726    1.1883   0.0693  2.49    0.013 *
y    0.5137    1.6715   0.3744  1.37    0.170  
x:y -0.1535    0.8577   0.1019 -1.51    0.132  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
x       1.188      0.842     1.037      1.36
y       1.672      0.598     0.803      3.48
x:y     0.858      1.166     0.702      1.05

Concordance= 0.551  (se = 0.041 )
Rsquare= 0.06   (max possible= 0.992 )
Likelihood ratio test= 6.18  on 3 df,   p=0.103
Wald test            = 6.31  on 3 df,   p=0.0976
Score (logrank) test = 6.38  on 3 df,   p=0.0943
```

My question is how to interpret the Score test pvalue (0.0943) vs the interaction term's pvalue (x:y, 0.132)?